# Why does seekg() work incorrectly when file is not read in binary mode?

Tags: c++, stream, fstream, binaryfiles, ifstream

I have a file named "**Sample.dat**" with the following contents:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
```

When I try to read the file **WITHOUT** using `std::ifstream::binary` mode I get incorrect output. Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inf("F:\\cpp_programming\\File_Input_Output\\Sample.dat");

    if(!inf)
    {
        std::cerr << "Uh oh, Sample.dat could not be opened!" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::string str1;
    inf.seekg(5);
    std::getline(inf, str1);
    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;

    inf.seekg(8, std::ios::cur);
    std::getline(inf, str1);
    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;

    inf.seekg(-15, std::ios::end);
    std::getline(inf, str1);
    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output(incorrect) is:

```
is line 1
e 2
his is line 4
```

I get correct output when I use `std::ifstream::binary` mode. Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inf("F:\\cpp_programming\\File_Input_Output\\Sample.dat", std::ifstream::binary);

    if(!inf)
    {
        std::cerr << "Uh oh, Sample.dat could not be opened!" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::string str1;
    inf.seekg(5);
    std::getline(inf, str1);
    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;

    inf.seekg(8, std::ios::cur);
    std::getline(inf, str1);
    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;

    inf.seekg(-15, std::ios::end);
    std::getline(inf, str1);
    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output(correct) is:

```
is line 1
line 2
his is line 4
```

Why does the binary mode give the correct output?

Comment: Probably because in text mode the line ending is `\n` and in binary mode it is `\r\n`.

Comment: The argument of `seekg` shall be [obtained by a previous successful call to one of the positioning functions](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/filebuf.virtuals#17), otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @nwp So the seekg() function counts `\n` as 1 character when in text mode and `\r\n` as 4 characters when in binary mode? Is this why there is a difference of 3 characters between the two outputs given above?

Comment: @aks: ASCII newlines are either 1 character, 0x0A, or 2 characters (carriage return, 0x0D, and linefeed, 0x0A).  Their could be a 4 character newline, but I haven't seen it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews If the difference between `\n` and `\r\n` is 1 character, why is there a difference of 3 characters between the two outputs?